# Receive an XML document sent through HTTP POST in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, http-post

I have an XML document being sent to me by HTTP POST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <DeliveryNotification eventType="newMessage">
    <requestUid>sms9676187</requestUid>
    <sentMessageUid>sms29282896</sentMessageUid>
    ....
  </DeliveryNotification>
```

Which I then receieve in a perl script using the param() subroutine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI qw/param/;
use Data::Dumper;

my @xml = param();
warn Dumper(@xml);
```

and when I Dumper the result I get:

```
$VAR1 = '<?xml version';
```

It seems to break the file whenever it runs into an '=' sign. If I remove the first eqauls sign to test, it just breaks at the next one. Can this only be solved from the side that is sending the data by escaping the equals or can I do something in Perl?

Comment: *How* is the data being sent? What is the content-type of the HTTP request? What does the body of the request look like?

Comment: How does the XML end up in the results of `param()`? Why dio you want to store those results into an array?  What do you want to do with the XML returned?  If you need to look into its contents, use an XML parser.

Comment: The data being sent is like a post query, but instead of being "id=22111&name=xxx" it's an XML document, so a string with the whole XML document.

I'm storing it in an array because when I store it in a scalar I just get "1". I'll use an XML parser once the data I receive is complete and not truncated after the = sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it your script looks something like:

```
#!env perl
use CGI qw( :standard );
use Data::Dumper;
my @xml = param();
warn Dumper(@xml);
```

`param()` expects a url-encoded list of parameters in the query string (GET or POST), and in list context returns the names of the parameters.

If you just want the raw data from the query string (and never expect to handle form data), use `query_string()` and submit the XML via a GET request instead.

[You can read the raw POST data via STDIN without using CGI, but there are caveats.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=131978)

Comment: Yes that's a little bit more like the full code I have. I added a more to my question to show the whole script. by query_string() do you mean: $ENV{QUERY_STRING}? cannot seem to find a query_string() sub

Comment: `use CGI qw( query_string );`

Comment: Ahh perfect there we go! Thanks! Get everything with query_string()

Comment: -1 `query_string` cannot possibly help with POST data, this is intended for GET. – Also, the Perlmonks article is outdated. Meanwhile, a proper API for accessing the request body has been added to CGI.pm.

Comment: hi daxim, I specifically mentioned that this would only work with GET requests and the CGI API for accessing the request body doesn't work with XML.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`param('POSTDATA')`](http://p3rl.org/CGI#HANDLING-NON-URLENCODED-ARGUMENTS).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use CGI qw();
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $xml = $cgi->param('POSTDATA');
```

Comment: I tried that one and I just got "undef" for the value of $xml

Answer (score -1):

You don't gives us much code to look at, so we can only guess what is the problem.
I'm 'guessing' the problem lays at the sending side.
All data in a HTTP POST needs to be URL encoded.
And since '=' is an unsafe character that needs to be encoded that could be your problem.

For more info on url encoding and HTTP POST have a look at:
[enter link description here](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/http_footnotes.html#urlencoding)

Comment: I added a bit more code. I also have a PHP script that when send the exact HTTP POST of the XML retrieves all the data, so I believe it's something on the PERL side

Comment: No, not all data in a HTTP POST needs to be URL encoded. This is only true for Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but the question shows application/xml.